# React native this.props.navigation.navigate undefined

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

**navigation.js**

```
       import React,{ Component} from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import  Login  from './screens/login'
import  SplashScreen  from './screens/splashScreen'

// export const Nav = createStackNavigator({
//     splashScreen: {  screen: SplashScreen  },
//     loginScreen: {  screen:Login  },
// },{ initialRouteName: 'splashScreen' })

// export default createAppContainer(Nav);

const Nav = createStackNavigator({
    loginScreen: { screen: Login },
     splashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'splashScreen',
    }
})
export default createAppContainer(Nav);
```

**splashscreen.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { appContainer  } from '../styleSheet'
import { Nav }  from  '../navigations'
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

class SplashScreen extends Component {

componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
       // alert('I will redirect')
        this.props.navigation.navigate("loginScreen");
    }, 3000);
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={appContainer.AppContainer}>
               <Text style={appContainer.splashSC}> Who Around Me  </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

 export default SplashScreen
```

**login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { appContainer,buttons } from '../styleSheet'

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <View style={appContainer.AppContainer}>

                    <Text style={buttons.loginBtnText}>
                        Login with Sim
                    </Text>
                </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Login
```

**App.js**

```
  /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import  SplashScreen  from './screens/splashScreen'
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import  Login  from './screens/login'
import { Nav }  from  './navigations'

const App = () => (
  <Nav  />
);

export default App;
```

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import App from "./src/App";

 AppRegistry.registerComponent("WhoAroundMe", () => App);
```

**this.props.navigation.navigate("loginScreen");** throws error

> this.props.navigation.navigate undefined

Could not able to resolve by doing alot google.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't clearly understand the problem well, but you can try adding SplashScreen in `createStackNavigator()` in `navigation.js` file

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    loginScreen: { screen: Login },
    splashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'splashScreen',
    }
})
export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

In your App.js file replace with this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Nav />  //instead of SplashScreen
);
```

Comment: it says splashScreen must be react component

Comment: did you import SplashScreen in navigation.js ?

Comment: Yes I did the same

Comment: But when I give initialRouteName it returns 500 error

Comment: I have added index.js file code in post, could you plz check once there

Comment: It saying syntax error near " { initialRouteName: 'splashScreen' }'

Comment: export const Nav = createStackNavigator({
    splashScreen: {  screen: SplashScreen  },
    loginScreen: {  screen:Login  },
    { initialRouteName: 'splashScreen' }
    // splashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen}
})

Comment: Do I need to add anything for intialRouteName

Comment: actually you are using an older version of react-navigation, maybe it's because of that

Comment: "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"

Comment: whats the version of your `react-navigation` ?

Comment: "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"

Comment: When I remove initialRouteName say splashscreen must be react component

Comment: try using createAppContainer() which is mandatory to use in react-navigation-3, I updated my answer

Comment: Same problem, if remove intialRoutename says says splashScreen must be react component, else if add initialRouteName says syntax error near initialRouteName

Answer (score 2):

It is because your SplashScreen Component is not declared as a route in react-navigation. when you create route, you can put SplashScreen as route and set it as initial route name.

```js
export const Nav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    splashScreen: {
      screen: SplashScreen
    },
    loginScreen: {
      screen:Login
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'splashScreen'
  }
)
```

Comment: it says splashScreen must be react component

Answer (score 2):

Pass the {...props} when calling SplashScreen component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import  SplashScreen  from './screens/splashScreen'
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import  Login  from './screens/login'
import { Nav }  from  './navigations'

const App = () => (
  <SplashScreen {...props} />
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Not working,  remove intialRoutename says says splashScreen must be react component, else if add initialRouteName says syntax error near initialRouteName

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import SplashScreen from "./splashScreen";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Nav from "./navigations";<----changes-----

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Nav />
    );
  }
}
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Login from "./login";
import SplashScreen from "./splashScreen";

//<------replace your code from here
const Nav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    loginScreen: { screen: Login },
    splashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "splashScreen"
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(Nav);
```

Comment: remove intialRoutename says says splashScreen must be react component, else if add initialRouteName says syntax error near initialRouteName

Comment: have you add splashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen}, in your export const Nav = createStackNavigator({
    loginScreen:{
        screen:Login
    }
})  navigation.js file ?

Comment: Yes changing to Nav has been done after answer given by @piyush

Comment: Sorry, I have re-updated the app.js and navigation.js file, Actually I am tyring everyone solution, to run it anyway

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I have updated my answer can you please check and try it

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was I was importing navigations.js in screen files.

Thanks all for your valuable comments I learned lots of things from you brothers

Comment: Happy to help :)